# For loop for computing two vectors in R

Tags: for-loop

Suppose i have a genotype dataset: geno

```
FID rs1 rs2 rs3
1   1   0   2
2   1   1   1
3   0   1   1
4   0   1   0
5   0   0   2
```

Another dataset is : coed

```
rs1 rs2 rs3
0.6 0.2 0.3
```

Do the following code:

```
geno$rs1 <- geno$rs1 * coed$rs1
geno$rs2 <- geno$rs2 * coed$rs2
geno$rs3 <- geno$rs3 * coed$rs3

sum3 <- rowSums(geno[,c(2:4)])
c <- cbind(geno,sum3)
```

I will get the output as i want

```
FID rs1 rs2 rs3 sum3
1   0.6 0   0.6 1.2
2   0.6 0.2 0.3 1.1
3   0   0.2 0.3 0.5
4   0   0.2 0   0.2
5   0   0   0.6 0.6
```

But i have thousands of SNPs, which i tried to build the below for loop

```
snp <- names(geno)[2:4]

geno.new <- numeric(0)

for (i in snp){
geno.new[i] = geno1[i] * coed[i]
}
```

The results is not what i would expected

```
$rs1
 [1] 0.6 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 

$rs2
 [1] 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.0 

$rs3
 [1] 0.6 0.3 0.3 0.0 0.6
```

Could any one help me to improve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did find the solution, see the code below:

```
## read datasets

geno <- read.table("Genotype.csv",header=T,sep=",")

dim(geno)

coed <- read.table("beta.csv",header=T,sep=",")

## define the snp name
snp <- names(geno)[2:4]

## building for loop

for (i in snp){
geno[i] <- geno[i] * coed[i]
}

## caculate the sums
sum <- rowSums(geno[,c(2:4)])

## combind the results
all <- cbind(geno,sum)
```